# Webpack dev server not watching files after changing name of root directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-dev-server

I recently changed the name of my root directory (where package.json and webpack.config.js sits) and now `webpack-dev-server` is not updating anytime I change my files.

Here's my webpack config:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/init.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "app.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: 'index.html'
    }
  }
};
```

And my directory looks like this (Client React is the folder that had its name changed):

[image]

Let me clarify that this worked fine before, so I really have no idea why this isn't working now.

Edit: Scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
```

Comment: do you have any value in scripts section of package.json?

Comment: @omerfaruk See edit.

Comment: Is "(Current)" part of your directory name?

Comment: @vincent Yes. I have another project (that I am keeping a backup of) which is obsolete in the same folder.

Comment: Then I guess it's probably related to the brackets. Try removing them and try again.

Comment: @vincent Okay that's really weird. Post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the brackets. Probably because they are not properly escaped by the watch module that webpack uses (`watchpack`) or the part that does the final watching in the System itself. I recommend you don't use any special characters inside directory- or filenames because of such bugs.